# Convert string to relative date

Tags: mysql, date, dayofweek, days

In PHP there is the `strtotime` function, and I can do this:

```
$friday = strtotime('FRIDAY 12:45:00', time());
```

PHP will give me a unix timestamp for the date and time.

**Note**: If today is Friday, then the timestamp will be today's date, otherwise it will be in the future.

Is there anyway to do the above with MySQL?

Comment: There are better ways to do this

Comment: @JohnConde: Any pointers would be appreciated, my only goal is to check if this day and time is in the past

Comment: @Drahcir you can never know that, since a friday (or any day) ALWAYS exists in the future and past.

Comment: @davey: Good point. That's what my **Note** is about above, if the day name is the same as today, then it's the current not past.

Comment: @davey: No, actually I see what you mean. It's confusing me, but you're right :-/

Comment: Store the date and time in a DATETIME field in your MySQL table. You can do anything with it then.

Comment: @davey, Can't do that because it's not for any specific date. But anyway I've figured out a better way for my need. I will change the question slightly and leave it open in case anyone has a solution.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Then you probably want to take a look at date('N'), it gives you the number of the day of the week (Monday = 1, Friday = 5), see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php